# Prolog Wumpus How to find a path in an unknown maze

Tags: prolog, maze, wumpus-world

How to find a path in an unknown maze in prolog? 
I am having initial position and no. of rows and columns, but no end position and I cannot give the rows*columns as end as I have to move recursively to find Wumpus, pit ,wall and an empty space in a maze.

Comment: Did you try searching this site for `[prolog] maze`? Show some attempt at what you tried so far and ask a more specific question.

Answer (score -1):

You can only find a path of the known part of a maze. For the unknown path you would need to maybe work with hypothesis and even propability might help valueing options.

The Hunt the Wumpus game maze discovery is nicely depicted by the original article from Gregory Yob which shows some gameplay. Whether this discovery is stable also depends on some assumptions that the tunnels do not change:

[image]

**Original Hunt the Wumpus BASIC Program from 1972**
https://www.atariarchives.org/bcc1/showpage.php?page=247

To allow experimentation with the original 1972 version of Hunt the Wumpus, I have translated the BASIC code into Prolog. It uses Erlang style programming, so there is not assert/retract. The game state is just passed along and modified along tail-recursive and mutally-recursive predicate calls.

But to embed it in some planning system, you would need to massage the code more, and remove the read_line/1 and write/1 and nl/1, and replace it by a modelling of an interaction between the player and the game.

**Tranlation to Prolog in Erlang Style**
https://github.com/jburse/jekejeke-samples/tree/master/pack/games